# React: Where to put API call to be made on state change

Tags: reactjs

I need to make an API call on state change in react

Which lifecycle method should I put this API call in?

`componentDidUpdate()`, `getDerivedStateFromProps()` or any other?

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be going for `componentDidUpdate()` if it doesn't affect the state.
`getDerivedStateFromProps()` mutates the state and therefore should only be used if your state relies on the `nextProps` the component will receive. It won't fire on your state modifications but could be used combined with `componentDidUpdate()` in a very few cases.

Here is a quick example using Redux of what you are willing to achieve, omitting on purpose actions, reducers and apis related files to avoid any confusion:

```
@connect(state => ({ searchResult: state.searchResult }))
class MassFetchingComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        search: '',
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevState.search!== this.state.search) {
            dispatch(searchAction(this.state.search));
        }
    }

    handleChange = search => this.setState({ search })

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Input value={this.state.search} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                { this.props.searchResult }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I used an Input for the example purpose but I wouldn't recommend doing this if your state changes at a fast pace. Using sockets would be an option there.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) - good place for remote endpoint calls or subscriptions
- [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) - good place for network requests "as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed)"

You may cancel or unsubscribe any lingering requests in [`componentWillUnmount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount).

Comment: If you may elaborate how to do this "You may cancel or unsubscribe any lingering requests in `componentWillUnmount`."

Comment: @Rahul It's API-specific. For example if you do `api.endpoint.subscribe()` in `componentDidMount`, then you'd call `api.endpoint.unsubscribe()` in `componentWillMount`.

Answer (score -2):

You should populate data with API call in the componentDidMount lifecycle method. This is so you can use setState to update your component when the data is retrieved.

[enter link description here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)

Comment: I agree that componentDidMount should be used to fetch your initial data but I don't think this is the point here. He is willing to make an api call anytime the state changes.